# How to convert single ObjectId to an array of ObjectIds in MongoDB Compass

Tags: arrays, mongodb, csv, aggregation-framework

I have a data that is set up like this in MongoDB Compass:

```
"person": "Isaac",
"city": { "$oid" : "049485053930a029g" }
```

I need it to be like this below,  as a single object can have multiple cities:

```
"person": "Isaac",    
"city": [{ "$oid" : "049485053930a029g" }]
```

I imported my data with a CSV file.
I tried to use this aggregation in Compass, but I got an error:

```
    {
    country: {$objectToArray:  "$country"} 
    }
    //$objectToArray requires a document input, found: objectId
```

WWhat solution can I implement to solve this problem?

I have a lot of data to add to my database, I do not want to do it manually on my back-end CMS.

Comment: do you want to update existing/inserted data or just need to format result in aggregation query?

Comment: I need to update it so it can be shown on my website. Currently it returns an error because of the bad field format (the field "country" in my backend accept an array of objects only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try an [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) query starting from MongoDB 4.2, to update all the document's `city` in an array,

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  {},
  [{
    $set: {
      city: ["$city"]
    }
  }]
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0o45srqT-Hk)